# How to properly get from development to production rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a working state of my rails 4 app. 
I have uploaded it to digital ocean. And am able to start a server with "rails server" command.

But my app keeps crashing with an error "killed" or other error.

Then I have tried to change from webrick to puma and still it stops to render the app after couple of minutes.

Do I need to start it in production environment? Or there is some other steps I am missing?

My goal is to run the server via ssh like: 
Screen Rails server -b "ip" -p 80 and for it to keep running till I shut it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Usually, an app isn't run in production using `rails s`. We run it using a production server, say, Puma or Phusion Passenger. This way, this process will remain running even if you close the SSH session. For deployment, maybe look at Capistrano to make it all easier to run in prod.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you point me how to start a server with puma? I though it runs also with" rails s".

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma